# search filter from xml in php

Tags: php, xml

I filtered whole title from my XML.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
        {

        $state=$_POST["state"];

        $title=$_POST["title"];


        $result = simplexml_load_file('sample.xml');
        $record = $result-> xpath('(/jobs/job[positiontitle="'.$title.'"])|(/jobs/job[state="'.$state.'"])');

         foreach ($record as $row):
$jobid=$row->jobid;

?>
        <li class="result"> 
        <a href="<?php print base_path(); ?>job/?<?php print $jobid;?>">
        <h3 class="title"><?php $title=$row->positiontitle; 
        echo $title; ?></h3>  
        </li>
 <?php 

         endforeach;
?>
```

Here my xml

```
<jobs>
<job>
<jobid>
<![CDATA[ 02304485 ]]>
</jobid>
<positiontitle>
<![CDATA[ Maintenance Manager ]]>
</positiontitle>
</job>
</jobs>
```

If I type the title "maintenance",the title should be filtered.In sql we can  filter by using like operation. Here what should do?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help if you use [normalize-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) in your xpath expression to strip the leading and trailing white-space.

You might change this line:

```
$record = $result-> xpath('(/jobs/job[positiontitle="'.$title.'"])|(/jobs/job[state="'.$state.'"])');
```

to this line:

```
$record = $result->xpath('/jobs/job[normalize-space(positiontitle)="' . $title . '"]|/jobs/job[normalize-space(jobid)="' . $state . '"]');
```